# How can I +1 to all numbers in a mySQL table column

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in mySQL that is laid out like so:

```
Firstname:
Surname:
School Year: (can be 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 or 13)
```

I need to add one to all numbers in the School Year column - is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: `UPDATE table SET school_year = school_year + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `update`

```
update the_table
   set school_year = school_year + 1;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e26b03/1

Comment: Thank you - thats exactly what I was hoping to do.